# OLAPQueryLog does not work for SSAS Tabular mode

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I running into a problem when I try to setup querylog in SSAS. The QueryLog Table name has been created already, and WRITE permissions on the table has given to the service account used to run SSAS. I've set the QueryLogSampling value to "1", but I'm not seeing anything come through.

I have seen a post here that mentions OlapQueryLog does not work for Tabular mode, but I can't seem to locate documentation around this. Is this true and can someone link to documentation somewhere?

Thanks,

Tho H. Le